# gTTS install via pip worked properly but importing it into program throws error

Tags: python

I reinstalled python (version 3.8.1, the newest release) on my Mac then used `sudo pip install gTTS`, which seems to have worked. Both gTTS and gTTS-token show up when I use `pip list`.

However, I tried this test program:

```
from gtts import gTTS 
import os 

mytext = 'Testing hello one two three'

language = 'en'

myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False) 

myobj.save("welcome.mp3") 

os.system("mpg321 test.mp3")
```

And the output was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/folder/ttstest1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
```

I don't understand why this isn't working because the library seems to have installed correctly.

Comment: Did you check if the "pip" you used is pip for python3? Bc, if you have python2, calling pip will calling python2 pip.

Comment: I did not. How could I check that, or alternatively, force it to use python 3 pip?

Comment: pip3 is linked to python 3.x